# ２分木へのデータの追加について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム, binary-tree

「アルゴリズムとデータ構造」紀平拓男／春日伸弥 著 （http://www.sbcr.jp/products/4797324198.html?sku=4797324198）第6章において 、２分木へのデータの追加のコードが紹介されています。
それを今Ruby版に置き換えたつもりなのですが、**二つ目のデータの追加のとき**に上手く動かなくて困っています。
どこを修正すればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
# -*- coding: cp932 -*-

# Node Class
class Node
  attr_reader :value, :left, :right
  def initialize(val)
    @value = val   # ノードが保持する値
    @left = nil    # 左側のノード
    @right = nil   # 右側のノード
  end 
end

# ノードを生成する
def create_new_node(val)
  newNode = Node.new(val)
  return newNode
end

# ノードの追加
def insert_tree(num, node = nil)
  # 1つも挿入されていない場合
  if node == nil
    @tree_root = create_new_node(num)
    return
  end 
  # num が現在の node の値よりも小さい場合
  if node.value > num
    if node.left != nil
      insert_tree(num, node.left)
    else
      node.left = create_new_node(num)
    end
  # num が現在の node の値以上の場合
  else
    if node.right != nil
      insert_tree(num, node.right)
    else
      node.right = create_new_node(num)
    end
  end
end

def print_tree(depth, node = nil)
  if node == nil
    return
  end
  print_tree(depth + 1, node.left)
  i = 0
  while i < depth
    printf "   "
    i += 1
  end
  printf("%d\n",node.value)
  print_tree(depth + 1, node.right)
end

def main
  action = nil
  while action != 0
    print_tree(0, @tree_root)
    printf("実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。\n 1 ：追加\t2 ：検索\t3 ：削除\t それ以外：終了>")
    action = gets.chomp.to_i
    case action
      when 1
        printf("1 ～100の範囲で，追加する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if (i < 1 || i > 100)
          continue
        end
        insert_tree(i, @tree_root)
      else
        break
    end
  end
end

main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr_reader` を `attr_accessor` に変更すれば動くのではないでしょうか．
`attr_reader` はgetterを自動生成するだけなので， `insert_tree(num, node = nil)` 内の

```
node.left = create_new_node(num)
node.right = create_new_node(num)
```

のところでエラーになってしまうと思います．

ちなみに，

- `attr_accessor` setter, getterを両方定義
- `attr_reader` getterのみ定義
- `attr_writer` setterのみ定義

となっています．

Comment: ご指摘のとおりattr_accessorに変更すると、node.leftおよびnode.rightの部分でエラーが起こっていたのがなおりました。

Answer (score 2):

別の修正案をしめします。
[お気楽 Ruby プログラミング入門 二分木](http://www.geocities.jp/m_hiroi/light/abcruby13.html)
のコードを参考にしています。

```
# coding: utf-8

# See http://www.geocities.jp/m_hiroi/light/abcruby13.html

# Node Class
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  def initialize(val)
    @value = val   # ノードが保持する値
    @left = nil    # 左側のノード
    @right = nil   # 右側のノード
  end
end

# ノードの追加
def insert_tree(num, node = nil)
  if node.nil?
    return Node.new(num)   # ノードを生成する
  elsif num < node.value
    node.left = insert_tree(num, node.left)
  elsif node.value < num
    node.right = insert_tree(num, node.right)
  end
  node
end

def find_tree(num, node = nil)
  while node
    if node.value == num
      return node
    elsif node.value < num
      node = node.left
    else
      node = node.right
    end
  end
  nil
end

# node 以下の最小値のノードを探す。
def search_min(node)
  node = node.left while node.left
  node
end

# node 以下の最小のノードを削除する
def delete_min(node)
  return node.right unless node.left
  node.left = delete_min(node.left)
  node
end

def delete_tree(num, node)
  if node
    if num == node.value
      if node.left.nil?
        return node.right
      elsif node.right.nil?
        return node.left
      else
        min_node = search_min(node.right)
        node.value = min_node.value
        node.right = delete_min(node.right)
      end
    elsif num < node.value
      node.left = delete_tree(num, node.left)
    else
      node.right = delete_tree(num, node.right)
    end
  end
  node
end

def print_tree(node = nil, depth = 0)
  return if node.nil?

  print_tree(node.left, depth + 1)
  printf "#{' ' * 4 * depth}#{node.value}\n"
  print_tree(node.right, depth + 1)
end

def ask(msg)
  print msg
  gets.chomp.to_i
end

def main
  tree_root = nil
  loop do
    print_tree(tree_root)
    case ask "実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。\n 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>"
    when 1
      i = ask '追加する数字を入力してください:'
      tree_root = insert_tree(i, tree_root)
    when 2
      i = ask '検索する数字を入力してください:'
      puts find_tree(i, tree_root).nil? ? "みつかりません\n" : "みつかりました\n"
    when 3
      i = ask '削除する数字を入力してください:'
      tree_root = delete_tree(i, tree_root)
    when 4
    # print_tree(tree_root)
    when 9
      break
    end
  end
end

main
```

- 2015-01-18:  追記
  print_tree を以下のようにすると、もうすこし tree らしい表示になります。
  参考： How to print binary tree diagram?　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335

コード：

```
INDENT_1 = '    '
INDENT_2 = ' |  '
INDENT_3 = '- '
def print_tree(node = nil)
  return if node.nil?

  def print_tree_sub(node, is_right, indent = '')
    print_tree_sub(node.right, true, "#{indent}#{is_right ? INDENT_1 : INDENT_2}") if node.right
    printf("#{indent}")
    printf(is_right ? ' /' : ' \\')
    printf(INDENT_3)
    printf("#{node.value}\n")
    print_tree_sub(node.left, false, "#{indent}#{is_right ? INDENT_2: INDENT_1}") if node.left
  end

  print_tree_sub(node.right, true) if node.right
  printf "#{node.value}\n"
  print_tree_sub(node.left, false) if node.left
end
```

出力例：

```
         /- 19
     /- 15
 /- 14
 |   \- 11
10
 |       /- 4
 |   /- 3
 |   |   \- 2
 \- 1
     \- 0
```