# ２分木のデータ追加、サーチ、削除について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム, binary-tree

「アルゴリズムとデータ構造」紀平拓男／春日伸弥 著 （http://www.sbcr.jp/products/4797324198.html?sku=4797324198）第6章において 、２分木のデータ追加、サーチ、削除のコードが紹介されています。
それを今Ruby版に置き換えたつもりなのですが、
53を追加、25を追加、85を追加、83を追加、52を追加したあと、53を削除すると「52が二つ表示される」不具合が生じます。
どこを修正すればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
# -*- coding: cp932 -*-

# Node Class
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right
  def initialize(val)
    @value = val   # ノードが保持する値
    @left = nil    # 左側のノード
    @right = nil   # 右側のノード
  end 
end

# ノードを生成する
def create_new_node(val)
  newNode = Node.new(val)
  return newNode
end

# ノードの追加
def insert_tree(num, node)
  # 1つも挿入されていない場合
  if node == nil
    @tree_root = create_new_node(num)
    return
  end 
  # num が現在の node の値よりも小さい場合
  if node.value > num
    if node.left != nil
      insert_tree(num, node.left)
    else
      node.left = create_new_node(num)
    end
  # num が現在の node の値以上の場合
  else
    if node.right != nil
      insert_tree(num, node.right)
    else
      node.right = create_new_node(num)
    end
  end
end

# ノードの検索
def find_value(node, val)
  # 自分より小さい値ならば、左側
  if node.value > val
    if node.left == nil
      return nil
    end
    return find_value(node.left, val)
  end
  # 自分より大きい値ならば、右側
  if node.value < val
    if node.right == nil
      return nil
    end
    return find_value(node.right, val)
  end
  return node 
end

# ノードの削除
def delete_tree(val)
  node = @tree_root
  parentNode = nil
  direction = 0
  # while文で削除すべき対象を見つける
  while (node != nil && node.value != val)
    if node.value > val
      parent_node = node
      node = node.left
      direction = -1
    else
      parent_node = node
      node = node.right
      direction = 1
    end
  end
  if node == nil
    return false
  end
  if node.left == nil || node.right == nil
    if node.left == nil
      if direction == -1
        parent_node.left = node.right
      end
      if direction == 1
        parent_node.right = node.right
      end
      if direction == 0
        @tree_root = node.right
      end
    else
      if direction == -1
        parent_node.left = node.left
      end
      if direction == 1
        parent_node.right = node.left
      end
      if direction == 0
        @tree_root = node.left
      end
    end
  else
    left_biggest = node.left
    parent_node = node
    direction = -1
    while left_biggest.right != nil
      parent_node = left_biggest
      left_biggest = left_biggest.right
      direction = -1
    end
    node.value = left_biggest.value
    if direction == -1
      parent_node.left = left_biggest.left
    else
      parent_node.right = left_biggest.left
    end
  end
  return true
end

def print_tree(depth, node = nil)
  if node == nil
    return
  end
  print_tree(depth + 1, node.left)
  i = 0
  while i < depth
    printf "   "
    i += 1
  end
  printf("%d\n", node.value)
  print_tree(depth + 1, node.right)
end

def main
  action = nil
  while action != 0
    print_tree(0, @tree_root)
    printf("実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。\n 1 ：追加\t2 ：検索\t3 ：削除\t それ以外：終了>")
    action = gets.chomp.to_i
    case action
      when 1
        printf("1 ～100の範囲で，追加する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if i < 1 || i > 100
          continue
        end
        insert_tree(i, @tree_root)
      when 2
        printf("検索する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if find_value(@tree_root, i) != nil
          printf("%dを発見しました\n", i)
        else
          printf("%dは見つかりませんでした\n", i)
        end
      when 3
        printf("削除する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if delete_tree(i)
          printf("%dを削除しました\n", i)
        else
          printf("%dは見つかりませんでした\n", i)
        end
      else
        break
    end
  end
end

main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最後の `direction = -1` が `direction = 1` でないといけないっぽい。

追加で `else` を `elsif` に、 `parentNode` を `parent_node` にしました。

#### パッチ差分

```ruby
@@ -62,9 +62,10 @@
 # ノードの削除
 def delete_tree(val)
   node = @tree_root
-  parentNode = nil
+  parent_node = nil
   direction = 0
   # while文で削除すべき対象を見つける
   while (node != nil && node.value != val)
     if node.value > val
       parent_node = node
@@ -78,26 +79,22 @@
   end
   if node == nil
     return false
-  end
-  if node.left == nil || node.right == nil
+ end
+  if (node.left == nil || node.right == nil)
     if node.left == nil
       if direction == -1
         parent_node.left = node.right
-      end
-      if direction == 1
+      elsif direction == 1
         parent_node.right = node.right
-      end
-      if direction == 0
+      elsif direction == 0
         @tree_root = node.right
       end
     else
       if direction == -1
         parent_node.left = node.left
-      end
-      if direction == 1
+      elsif direction == 1
         parent_node.right = node.left
-      end
-      if direction == 0
+      elsif direction == 0
         @tree_root = node.left
       end
     end
@@ -108,7 +105,7 @@
     while left_biggest.right != nil
       parent_node = left_biggest
       left_biggest = left_biggest.right
-      direction = -1
+      direction = 1
     end
     node.value = left_biggest.value
     if direction == -1
```

#### コード (更新分)

```ruby
# -*- coding: cp932 -*-

# Node Class
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right
  def initialize(val)
    @value = val   # ノードが保持する値
    @left = nil    # 左側のノード
    @right = nil   # 右側のノード
  end 
end

# ノードを生成する
def create_new_node(val)
  newNode = Node.new(val)
  return newNode
end

# ノードの追加
def insert_tree(num, node)
  # 1つも挿入されていない場合
  if node == nil
    @tree_root = create_new_node(num)
    return
  end 
  # num が現在の node の値よりも小さい場合
  if node.value > num
    if node.left != nil
      insert_tree(num, node.left)
    else
      node.left = create_new_node(num)
    end
  # num が現在の node の値以上の場合
  else
    if node.right != nil
      insert_tree(num, node.right)
    else
      node.right = create_new_node(num)
    end
  end
end

# ノードの検索
def find_value(node, val)
  # 自分より小さい値ならば、左側
  if node.value > val
    if node.left == nil
      return nil
    end
    return find_value(node.left, val)
  end
  # 自分より大きい値ならば、右側
  if node.value < val
    if node.right == nil
      return nil
    end
    return find_value(node.right, val)
  end
  return node 
end

# ノードの削除
def delete_tree(val)
  node = @tree_root
  parent_node = nil
  direction = 0
  # while文で削除すべき対象を見つける
  while (node != nil && node.value != val)
    if node.value > val
      parent_node = node
      node = node.left
      direction = -1
    else
      parent_node = node
      node = node.right
      direction = 1
    end
  end
  if node == nil
    return false
 end
  if (node.left == nil || node.right == nil)
    if node.left == nil
      if direction == -1
        parent_node.left = node.right
      elsif direction == 1
        parent_node.right = node.right
      elsif direction == 0
        @tree_root = node.right
      end
    else
      if direction == -1
        parent_node.left = node.left
      elsif direction == 1
        parent_node.right = node.left
      elsif direction == 0
        @tree_root = node.left
      end
    end
  else
    left_biggest = node.left
    parent_node = node
    direction = -1
    while left_biggest.right != nil
      parent_node = left_biggest
      left_biggest = left_biggest.right
      direction = 1
    end
    node.value = left_biggest.value
    if direction == -1
      parent_node.left = left_biggest.left
    else
      parent_node.right = left_biggest.left
    end
  end
  return true
end

def print_tree(depth, node = nil)
  if node == nil
    return
  end
  print_tree(depth + 1, node.left)
  i = 0
  while i < depth
    printf "   "
    i += 1
  end
  printf("%d\n",node.value)
  print_tree(depth + 1, node.right)
end

def main
  action = nil
  while action != 0
    print_tree(0, @tree_root)
    printf("実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。\n 1 ：追加\t2 ：検索\t3 ：削除\t それ以外：終了>")
    action = gets.chomp.to_i
    case action
      when 1
        printf("1 ～100の範囲で，追加する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if i < 1 || i > 100
          continue
        end
        insert_tree(i, @tree_root)
      when 2
        printf("検索する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if find_value(@tree_root, i) != nil
          printf("%dを発見しました\n", i)
        else
          printf("%dは見つかりませんでした\n", i)
        end
      when 3
        printf("削除する数字を入力してください:")
        i = gets.chomp.to_i
        if delete_tree(i)
          printf("%dを削除しました\n", i)
        else
          printf("%dは見つかりませんでした\n", i)
        end
      else
        break
    end
  end
end

main
```

Comment: 「最後の direction = -1 が direction = 1 でないといけない」理由がわかったので簡単に記しておきます。

いま削除したいノードは子孫をもつノードである。
よって、左側の子孫で最大のものを探し、それをnodeに代入することになる。
さて、左側の子孫で最大のものを探しているのだから、direction = 1である。

Comment: なるほど、私が気づいた理由は、`direction=-1` を `-1` で上書きしていたことがきっかけでした。「同値二重代入は大抵バグ」という見方からです（単なる経験則）。回答段階では「削除したいノードが左右両方をもっていた場合木構造を崩さないように入れ替えなければならない」というところであるというところまで認識しましたが、実装が正しいのか検証はしていませんでした。おっしゃるように「左側から最大値を探す」という流れですね。補足情報として、ここは「右側から最小値を探す」でも同様のことができたと思います。また、実装は、 while でまわす他に再帰でも書けます。私の最初に頭に浮かんだのは再帰実装で、while ってどうすんだったかというところでギブアップしましたw。私の lazy な回答を見抜き、適切なフィードバックをありがとうございました。勉強させてもらってます。

Answer (score 1):

以前にあった質問 [２分木へのデータの追加について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4704) での katoy の回答のコードでは、質問文にある追加・挿入操作を行うとつぎのように正常動作します。書籍のコードとは趣が異なるコードになっていますが、比較検討してみてはいかがでしょうか？(コード作成時に参照している web ページも参照してください)

```
実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。
 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>1
追加する数字を入力してください:53
53
実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。
 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>1
追加する数字を入力してください:25
    25
53
実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。
 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>1
追加する数字を入力してください:85
    25
53
    85
実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。
 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>1
追加する数字を入力してください:83
    25
53
        83
    85
実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。
 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>1
追加する数字を入力してください:52
    25
        52
53
        83
    85
実行する操作のタイプを入力してください。
 1:追加 2：検索  3:削除 4: 表示 9:終了>3
削除する数字を入力してください:53
    25
        52
83
    85
```